# how to convert file into binary using java

Tags: java

```
try
{
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File("Binary.txt"));
    byte[] infoBin=new byte[fis.available()];
    fis.read(infoBin);
    for (byte b : infoBin)
    {
        String bin=Integer.toBinaryString(b);
    }
}
```

How to read a file and convert that file contents into binary then write the binary to a new file using java

After Binary conversion, i don't know  how to write the string bin into the new file ?

Comment: use `FileOutputStream`
The `java.io.FileOutputStream.write(byte[] b)` method writes `b.length bytes` from the specified byte array to this file output stream.

Comment: All files are already binary. Question is unclear. NB Classic misuse of `available()`. See the [Javadoc.: 'It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available())

Answer (score 0):

//reading from file

```
byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Binary.txt"));
```

//saving to file

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Binary.txt");
fos.write(array );
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to read a file and convert that file contents into binary

They already are binary.

> then write the binary to a new file using java

There's no need to waste memory, or assume the file fits into memory, or assume the file size fits into an `int`. Memorise the following loop for copying between streams in Java:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```